# Asymptotics of functions $\int_a^\infty dt \ q(t) e^{- i x t }$ where $q'(t)$ not absolutely integrable?

Tags: functions, asymptotics, fourier-transform

In Olver's [Asymptotics and Special Functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780125258500/asymptotics-and-special-functions), he gives a statement on page 75: For the integral
$$
I(x) := \int_a^\infty dt \ e^{i x t } q(t) \ ,
$$
if $q(t)$ is continuous and $q'(t)$ is absolutely convergent on $[a,\infty)$ then the asymptotics of $I(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ are given by
$$
I(x) \approx \frac{i}{x} e^{i a x} q(a) + \ldots
$$
to leading order. Taking $\mathrm{Im}[I(x)]$ then gives you information about the sine-transform of $q(t)$.

**My question is:** What can you say about the sine-transform if $q(t)$ is not absolutely integrable? To be specific, what if I have a convergent integral like
$$
J(x) = \int_0^\infty dt \ \sin(x t) \log(t) e^{-t} 
$$ 
and I want access to the asymptotics as $x\to\infty$? The function $q(t) = \log(t) e^{-t}$ has a derivative which is not absolutely integrable on $[0,\infty)$ (even though this integral is convergent).

Is there a way to get asymptotics in an example like this? How can you deal with this?

P.S. I know that the integral $J(x)$ can be done explicitly, but I am interested in how to access the asymptotics by looking at the integral.

Comment: I don't think you can say anything more than the fact that it goes to zero at infinity by Riemann Lebesgue. But I might be mistaken.

Comment: I don't understand your P.S, it is because $F(s)= \int_0^\infty \log(t)e^{-st}dt$ has a closed-form ($(s F(s))' = -1/s+C$) that we can say something of your Fourier transform. If we only had $|f(t)| \le |\log(t) e^{-t}|$ the asymptotic could be anything.

Comment: What I meant by my PS is that I would be really interested to know if there are ways of deriving asymptotics for such integral transforms without knowing how to integrate $q(t)$. For example if one would have a more complicated $q(t)$ function. Basically I am wondering if there are more general versions of Olver's above theorem for oscillatory integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one catch-all formula, but there are various generalizations of Laplace's method and the saddle point method. In this example, it can be shown that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{i x t} e^{-t} \ln t \, dt \sim
e^{-t} \bigg\rvert_{t = 0} \int_0^{i \epsilon} e^{i x t} \ln t \, dt \sim
i \int_0^\infty e^{-x u} \ln u \, du.$$
Olver's book has a section on logarithmic singularities.